# How pause Watir script to allow user to click, and capture what they clicked on.

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir

I am trying to figure out on a Watir browser with ruby, how to use a mouse click and grab the element. Mostly what I find is using css selectors to identify elemnts but that is not my issue. I also find how to click the ouse, which is also not my issue.

I want to first stop when a user clicks on my broswer then give them the option to extract the element being clicked. I intend to use this element in the code to drive the rest of the program.

Now whether its xpath or what ever it is, I have search and am unable to get the return of the mouse click. Any help is appreciated.

I use:

`browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox) // or chrome`
`browser.goto("website.com")`
//ideally at this step I want to wait the script for user input
//if they click then I identify the element they click
Then later..
`doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)`

Comment: Watir isn't designed to wait for user input in the middle of execution. You'll need to know ahead of time what the browser is to do.

Comment: Ok do you know of an alternative or can you think of platform i can build my tool with.

Comment: Would it potentially work to use `execute_script`?  could he write something in JS that the browser could execute to wait for user input, capture the events  and return something about that was clicked to Watir?  That's likely kinda advanced JS scripting, but seems within the capabilities of JS (although I'd need help myself from an 'front end' type dev who was really good with JS)

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden I believe you are talking to Titus, If you simply write the comment like this, he would not be notified unless Titus has raised this question, Please include his name so that he would be notified.